# Change colour of non transparent SKSpriteNode (Swift)

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, sprite

I have an SKSpriteNode which is an image. The image is a red shape I have made. The reason it is an image and not a shape node is because it is an odd shape, which needs to be made as an image. This image has a transparent background.

Is there a way I can change the colour of the non-transparent part of the SKSpriteNode?

Thanks!

Comment: You'll just have to use another image, or recreate the shape yourself in code. There isn't any way to change the color of an image besides changing the alpha for opacity I believe.

Comment: There's no way to alter an image like that. You may need to use an image editing software to create a second image and change the node to that.

Comment: @manwholikesspritekit Can you upload that image, as well as image which represents desired result ?

Answer (score -1):

Anyways, you should be able to use [color](https://developer.apple.com/library/SpriteKit/Reference/SKSpriteNode_Ref/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/SKSpriteNode/color) and [colorBlendFactor](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/SpriteKit/Reference/SKSpriteNode_Ref/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/SKSpriteNode/colorBlendFactor) properties to colorize the texture :

```
sprite.colorBlendFactor = 1 //default is 0.0

sprite.color = SKColor.greenColor()
```

From the docs:

> The value must be a number between 0.0 and 1.0, inclusive. The default
>   value (0.0) indicates the color property is ignored and that the
>   texture’s values should be used unmodified. For values greater than
>   0.0, the texture is blended with the color before being drawn to the scene.

Also there is a [colorizeWithColor](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/SpriteKit/Reference/SKAction_Ref/#//apple_ref/occ/clm/SKAction/colorizeWithColor:colorBlendFactor:duration:) action which can animates color and colorBlendFactor properties to their new vaules.